# Does a low-profile graphics card exist that can do dual monitor VGA output to 2048x1152 resolution?

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, multiple-monitors

I have a 23" Samsung monitor for my Dell Vostro 220s machine.

Unfortunately, the supplied graphics card cannot meet the top resolution over VGA.

My requirements therefore are:

Low-profile PCIe card
VGA Output of at least 2048 x 1152
Dual monitor output

**Are there any graphics cards that can meet these requirements?**

Comment: Is VGA a requirement?  Dongles wouldn't work?

Comment: @Nifle, Diago - If this question is not 'related to computer hardware in some way' than I don't know what is ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this good enough for you? (Notice second output resolution is lower)

[Matrox G550](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/g_series/g550lppcie/)

- Matrox DualHead to use 2 monitors at
  a time (in "independent" or
  "stretched" mode)
- AGP card compatible    with all AGP
  slots (AGP 1x, 2x, 4x,    and 8x)
- Passive cooling (heat sink    with no
  fan) for silent operation and
  extra reliability
- TV-output support    (composite video
  and S-video, NTSC or    PAL)
- Easy-to-use Matrox PowerDesk driver
  interface Matrox Clone to view a copy
  of one display on the other display
- Matrox Multi-Display Zoom to view a
  portion of one display full-screen on
  the other display
- Matrox DVDMax to    view
  hardware-accelerated video
  playback in a video window on one
  display and full-screen on the other 
  display
- Support for displays with    special
  aspect ratios

  **Maximum resolutions (per display)**

  - Digital: 1280 x 1024
  - Analog, main display: 2048 x 1536
  - Analog secondary display: 1600 x 1200

Comment: Hi, thanks for putting so much effort into your answer, unfortnately thought the card I need is PCIe. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jon - there is a PCIe version - updated the link